# Bash 3 compatible code

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

I have this bash function:

```
zmx () { 

 "$@" 2> >( while read line; do echo -e "r2g: $line"; done ) > \
     >( while read line; do echo -e "r2g: $line"; done )

}
```

what it does is append "r2g:" to each line of stdout/stderr.

You use it like so:

```
$ zmx echo "foo"
```

and you will get:

```
r2g: foo
```

It works great in Bash4, but seems to break with Bash3 when running on a Mac.

Does anyone know how to convert it to idiomatic Bash3?

Comment: Is it giving an error in bash v3?

Comment: it's a syntax error, yeah, will update the OP

Comment: seems to work for me on macos using bash v3.2.

Comment: Do you mean that it's supposed to "prepend" `r2g:` to each line? Appending it would put it at the end.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Answer (score 1):

work on bash 3.2.57

```
MacBook-Pro:~ em$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

MacBook-Pro:~ em$ zmx() { "$@" 2> >(while read line;do echo -e "err: $line"; done ) > >(while read line; do echo -e "std: $line"; done); }
MacBook-Pro:~ em$ zmx bash -c "ls -1 /etc/ | head -5 ; cat /etc/shadow"
std: afpovertcp.cfg
std: afpovertcp.cfg~orig
std: aliases
std: aliases.db
std: apache2
err: cat: /etc/shadow: No such file or directory
```